# Get Data from url to use on next page

Tags: php, mysql, url, hyperlink

I have a report that I also have a link set up on. Here is the snippet of code for the link:

```
<td><?php echo "<a href=http://www.ems-complete.com/patient-care-report/form/7/".$row2['id'].">Document Report</a>" ;?> </td>
```

When this link is clicked I need the `$row2['id']` stored so I can use it to display another report.

Comment: The whole URL will be in $_SERVER in the page you call. Parse it from there and pass it on.

Comment: Split the url, and get the last "/".

Comment: Split the url. Send an ajax request. Pass your variable $row2['id']. Fire Sql.

Answer (score 0):

You could link an internal script that save that ID and redirect the user to the right link. So you'll have

```
<td><?php echo "<a href=\"goto.php?id=".$row2['id']."\">Document Report</a>" ;?> </td>
```

And your `goto.php` script will be something like:

```
<?php
//Save somewhere $_GET['id']
header('Location: http://www.ems-complete.com/patient-care-report/form/7/'.$_GET['id']);
?>
```

Of course you should also validate `$_GET['id']` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

your login page looks like this:

```
http://www.ems-complete.com/component/users/?view=login
```

the property following the ? is available by the next page via a $_GET['view'] request.
if you try to structure your url so that $row2['id'] gets assigned to a variable the same way, something like this:

```
<td><?php echo "<a href=http://www.ems-complete.com/patient-care-report/form/7/?someproperty=".$row2['id'].">Document Report</a>" ;?> </td>
```

then you should be able to get it on the next page like

```
$newvariable = $_GET['someproperty'];
```